# Does Docker have log statuses, e.g. error, warn, info?

Tags: node.js, docker, logging, docker-compose

For example in Node.js container I do:
`throw new Error('lol');` or `console.error('lol');`
But when I open container logs: `docker-compose logs -f  nodejs`
there are no any statuses or colors like all logs have info status.

I use Datadog to collect logs from container - it also mark all logs as 'info'.

Comment: Use a logger like winston. https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston

Comment: In that case I will have two types of logs - one from Docker, and one from Winston? Is it possible to achieve single log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker logs` and similar just collect the stdout and stderr streams from the main process running inside the container.  There's not a "log level" associated with that, though some systems might treat or highlight the two streams differently.

As a basic example, you could run

```
docker run -d --name lister --rm busybox ls /
docker logs lister
```

The resulting file listing isn't especially "error" or "debug" level.

The production-oriented setups I'm used to include the log level in log messages (in a Node context, I've used the [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) logging library), and then use a tool like [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org) to collect and parse those messages.

Comment: Is it ok to have two logs, one from container and one from Winston?

Comment: @Molarro Afaik Winston would write to stdout. You don't need to count it as a separate log process or something. Just replace your console.log with Winston's logger.

Comment: Ok, and last question. Every process has its own sdout and stderr streams? Or they are for all processes?

Comment: Every process has its own stdout and stderr.  If you use the shell construct `some_command >out.log 2>err.log` that redirects them separately.